# Is it possible to have a V65/I if the following 2 chords are V42/iv then iv6

Tags: chord-theory

I am a little stuck on the use of secondary dominants in relation to an assignment I have. I have posted the whole section for context, however I am confused on the first bar of the gm phrase.

From my understanding of secondary dominants, the chord preceding the iv6 would be a V42/iv (G major 4-2), with the iv being c minor. As that chord is the major version of the key signature, am I correct in assuming that the preceding chord of that would be a V65/major I chord?

If I am completely wrong in what I've written down, I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

[image: context]

[image: focus area]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off, regardless of what you call the second chord, the first chord is minor, not major.

I don’t think calling it V65/I really adds much to the analysis here; I see what you’re getting at, but it just seems like an unnecessary detail to me. When we hear the passage, we’ll surely take it as a normal V65 (after all, the chords are the same) that turns out to just be a passing chord into the following harmony (this is the Burstein/Straus book, right? I think they’ve talked about passing V6 chords at this point…)

For the most part, there really isn’t such a thing as secondary dominants of modal mixtures of I, because a) the chord is the same as its diatonic counterpart, so it tends to come off as overanalysis and b) any kind of “secondary” dominant of I is just a primary dominant. Again, I see your point: the chord does kind of lead to the next chord in a dominant-like way, almost like it’s a V65 of V/iv, or V65/V/iv! But, especially in the more Schenkerian approach of Burstein/Straus, that second chord doesn’t *really* have dominant function (secondary or otherwise) because the supposed leading tone doesn’t resolve. This is just a passing chord harmonizing ^7 in the bass passing down to ^6.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you’re fine labeling it as V65/I.

The clearest way to show the “I” to “V42” relationship is to write both. Under the chord following, write a “I” then draw a vertical line to the left of it, connect a horizontal line underneath it going right, connect a 3rd line vertically to the left of it. Under this new “box” draw your secondary dominant label.

Your school may not be teaching you this method of labeling, but it is a clear way to show multiple tonal relationships for chords. Using this method, you can show that the G7 indeed resolved the D7 while simultaneously setting up a move to iv6.